# Export an XML Generated in SQL SERVER to disk location

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please Help me for this

I have a query that returns a result set... I made it into a XML file using `FOR XML AUTO`.
How can I save that XML file onto my hard disk into a file like `C:Temp\Test.XML`?

```
SELECT * FROM MENU_MAST FOR XML AUTO
```

I tried this also

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(255);
select @cmd = 'bcp "select * FROM MENU_MAST row for xml auto, root(''rows''), elements" ' +
              'queryout "d:\temp\sample.xml" -S UMSDEV -T -w -r -t';

exec xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

This returns the XML I want to export it into hard disk location as an XML file from the query itself.. please help me..

Comment: look either at **bcp** or use the right click in the Management studio on the result set

Comment: What's wrong with your `bcp` command?  It works for me

Comment: am accessing a database hosted on server.which requires a username and  password to get the instance.. but i dnt know how to give the user name and password  with the instance we are created with the above

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is not a file IO application.

As you have discovered, there are a variety of ways to achieve this, but all are to a certain extent, workarounds and bodges to make SQL Server do what it is not designed to do.

As an alternative to your `xp_cmdshell` which is rarely to be recommended, you could consider

- a `CLR` stored procedure
- an SSIS package
- writing some application logic in another language as a discrete application.

Comment: @KrishKvR The CLR stored procedure is on the SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

Send that XML to your front end code and try an export from there

Comment: No i have to do it from the back end itself... because i made a stored procedure. that is executed by a job scheduling...

Comment: Or you could put the scheduling on the application tier?